# Is there a free "Part-Handwriting" Font?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

Are there fonts that try to straddle the boundary between computer fonts (serif, non-serif, monospace) and hand-written fonts?  I am thinking of something more casual than a precise computer font but not as flowy or cursive as many handwriting or script fonts.

Ideally, it would also be free to use as a webfont and macos font.

Comment: Have you looked at [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Handwriting&preview.size=15)?

Comment: Comic Sans was pretty much designed for this purpose. – Not saying it is a good choice but it seems like what you are after...

Comment: yes, I have looked at google fonts, though I missed the link.  julian's advice helped.  https://dogemuchwow.com/free-alternatives-to-comic-sans-ms/ has a collection of google fonts that are worth considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Andika from SIL. It's open source.

Comment: beautiful font, but not handwritten enough for me.  would make a great computer font if it came in mono...

Comment: You want monospaced? Try Codelia, Comic Code and others from Tabular Type Foundry by Toshi Omagari, a really lovely guy.
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tabular-type-foundry/codelia/
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tabular-type-foundry/comic-code/